# Use Vuejs with PHP MySQL in local environment (XAMPP for example)

Tags: php, mysql, vuejs2

So, I've been taking a course on Vue.js.

Before, I've made small projects where I've used jQuery to make ajax calls to local PHP files, that then connects to a MySQL database in phpmyadmin. Just a simple CRUD application.

Using Vue, I'm struggling to figure out how to connect with PHP and MySQL in a similar way. The course has gone into the Vue CLI and using webpack to set up a project and then import components and so on. I understand when using "run dev" it sets up a node server and displays the app. XXAMP, which I've used before, just loads a bank page.

Is there a way I can harness the full extent of Vue but used with a locally hosted PHP / MySQL backend? If not, what technology do I need to use / learn for a full stack app?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you step a bit out of your comfort zone for this one.

Doing it basic like that via XAMPP, etc, is fine, but why not use something like Laravel together with Vue. Even officially the frameworks collaborate, and there are lots of examples of combined usage.

Also, Laravel makes sure that it sets you up with a local development environment without much fuss, and also utilizes PHP's own built-in development server, rendering your need for XAMPP obsolete. For starters check out this [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-guestbook-with-laravel-and-vuejs).

Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Thank for the answer and link! I shall check it out and yes, step out the comfort zone!

Comment: Turn the sound off, ignore the language and this youtube set of three tutorials is great, https://youtu.be/RfLU7Lvkl9k